# Log Activity for my arduino controller android app

Tags: android, xml, logging, android-logcat

I'm creating a home automation android application with my arduino uno and bluetooth module. Everything works fine already. It can scan, connect, on/off bluetooth, control the bulb on and off using buttons and switch control.

The only lucking in my app is a Log Activity for my on and off switch controls which is my biggest problem. The Log Activity will suppose to be below the 3 switches with time and switch name that was turned on. I've been searching tutorials for it but still I'm a failure in creating it. What should be the possible things/tutorials/class for a Log Activity in same XML file. Any replies will be so much appreciated. Thank you.[image]

Comment: So your getting the database back but your view is not working?

Comment: nope. there will be no database in here. once the app will be exit those will be deleted also and will not be saved.

Comment: Sorry, I mean Data, my fingers are still waiting for my coffee to enter the blood stream.  So your getting your stream of data back from the Arduino and your app is the issue ?

Comment: Yes. The app is the problem. I dont know how.

Comment: So step one, make sure your getting the data back you expect from the arduino, what happens as a serial event while using the terminal provided with editor can be different once it runs on its own.